# Simple function in python

Tags: python-3.x

My program is to return the string repeated n times separated by the string delim. example repeat("ho",3,",").

```
def repeat():
    string=input("enter a string:")
    n=int(input("enter how many times to repeat:"))
    delim=(",")
    return string,n,delim
print (repeat())
```

I need to change the output to (hi,hi,hi) instead of this.

---

enter a string:hi

---

enter how many times to repeat:3

---

('hi', 3, ',')

Comment: The only problem im having now is that I cant get it to print by string with , inbetween each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the `.join()` method of strings to concatenate your strings.  For example:

```
', '.join(['yo']*4)
Out[4]: 'yo, yo, yo, yo'
```

There's some other issues in your code, the biggest of which I'd say is that your method `repeat()` should not be responsible for taking user input.  Move that into `main()` and delegate `repeat()` to only performing string operations.

Comment: what do I return into main, so that i do not get the error that string=input is not defined?